# Lock scroll before animation and unlock after

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Is there anyway that i can lock the window scroll when a animation start?

I have this particular animation:

```
Element.animate({
 opacity: 1,
 left: '0px'
});
```

And i want LOCK the window scroll before. I know how to unlock, in the callback:

```
Element.animate({
 opacity: 1,
 left: '0px'
}, function(){
 // UNLOCK HERE
});
```

But what about LOCK the window scroll before the animation start? This is possible???

I want force the visitor to see the animation, then he/she can scroll again..

Thanks!!

Comment: Hey there, you need to add more info! unlock what? I don't understand the context of lock and unlock. Add more code, share a demo link or JSfiddle, or add screenshots!!!!!!!!!!!!

Comment: It's impossible. window scroll is a system feature

Comment: You could use pop up dialog to show your animation, so that user have to close the dialog to do any other things in the site.

Comment: is not impossible, i can set the body to overflow hidden, this is not my question hind.. i just want to know how to call a function before the animation..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
$("div").animate({
 opacity: 1,
 left: '0px'
}, {
  duration:3000,
  start:function() {
    $("body").css("overflow","hidden")
  },
  complete:function() {
    $("body").css("overflow","scroll")
  }
});
```

```css
body {
  overflow:scroll;
}

div {
  position:relative;
  left:200px;
  opacity:0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>abc</div>
```

Comment: Perfect! This is exactly what i was looking for.. thank you very much guest271314

Answer (score 0):

```
document.body.style.overflow = "hidden";
Element.animate({
    opacity: 1,
    left: '0px'
    }, function(){
         document.body.style.overflow = "";
});
```

JsBin example: http://jsbin.com/nonodobavo/1/ - Clicking enables and disables scroll.